# How to get attribute ID to parameter of function js

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, element

I need put 5 images on page like thumbnail, and after click show the lightbox. I need put ID of element what I create to function like parameter. But i cant get ID. I was looking for this problem here and with google but nothings work :( It is project to school and I can use only html, css and javascript, I can not use jquery. Thanks. Here is my code:

```js
function onloadpg() {
    for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    x[i] = document.createElement("IMG");

        x[i].setAttribute("src", "images/" + (i+1) + ".jpg");
        x[i].setAttribute("width", "250");
        x[i].setAttribute("height", "200");
        x[i].setAttribute("alt", fotky.title);
        x[i].setAttribute("title", fotky.title);
        x[i].setAttribute("id", i+1);
        x.setAttribute("onclick", zobraz(x.getAttribute('id')), nacitaj(x.getAttribute('id')));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**
You could see in the browser console the message :

> Uncaught TypeError: x.setAttribute is not a function

**Solution :**
You need to use `x[i]` instead of `x` to target the current element by index in :

```
x.setAttribute("onclick", zobraz(x.getAttribute('id')), nacitaj(x.getAttribute('id')));
^________________________________^______________________________^
```

Should be :

```
x[i].setAttribute("onclick", "zobraz("+x[i].getAttribute('id')+")", "nacitaj("+x[i].getAttribute('id')+")");
^^^^_________________________^_______^^^^^^___________________^^^^___________^^^^^^___________________^^^^^
```

Note also that you've to add quotes `"` and concate variables.

**NOTE :** You should define the variable `x` as array :

```
var x = [];
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function onloadpg() {
  var x = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x[i] = document.createElement("IMG");

    x[i].setAttribute("src", "images/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
    x[i].setAttribute("width", "250");
    x[i].setAttribute("height", "200");
    x[i].setAttribute("alt", "fotky.title");
    x[i].setAttribute("title", "fotky.title");
    x[i].setAttribute("id", i + 1);
    x[i].setAttribute("onclick", "zobraz("+x[i].getAttribute('id')+")", "nacitaj("+x[i].getAttribute('id')+")");
    
    document.body.innerHTML += x[i].outerHTML+"<br>";
  }
}

function zobraz(id) {
  alert('zobraz : '+id);
}

function nacitaj(id) {
  alert("nacitaj : "+id);
}

onloadpg();
```

Comment: thank you, I had x[i] there but if I try something other, a remove it and I forgot take it back... but I try your code but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score -1):

```
function onloadpg(element_id) {

    var elem = document.getElementById(element_id);

    for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    x[i] = document.createElement("IMG");

    x[i].setAttribute("src", "images/" + (i+1) + ".jpg");
    x[i].setAttribute("width", "250");
    x[i].setAttribute("height", "200");
    x[i].setAttribute("alt", fotky.title);
    x[i].setAttribute("title", fotky.title);
    x[i].setAttribute("id", i+1);
    x.setAttribute("onclick", zobraz(x.getAttribute('id')),nacitaj(x.getAttribute('id')));
}

onloadpg("element_id");
```